# how to add event listener to cookie so that to notify when a cookie gets updated or expired

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, cookies, redux

I want to add an event listener to Cookie.
My objective is to call an function, once one of the cookies get expired.

I tried the following given in mozilla:-

```
 browser.cookies.onChanged.addListener(listener)
 browser.cookies.onChanged.removeListener(listener)
 browser.cookies.onChanged.hasListener(listener)
```

but its not working in chrome browser.

I seacrhed google but could not get any help

Any help in this regard as how to add event listener to cookie

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/cookies/onChanged says this works in Chrome, FF, and Opera.

Comment: browser object itself is not available in chrome console.

Comment: I think this is only for use in extensions. The documentation is in the Add-ons section.

Comment: hey any idea? how to add it in plain javascript. down with this issue since last two days

Comment: @newbieeeeeeee: there isn't a way to use it in plain JS; write your own hammer-based event launcher.

Comment: HI dsndavis, I am unaware of hammer based event launching?
ANy good lead or starting point in this regard?

Answer (score 12):

Right now, there is **no** API for watching the cookies.
This `browser.cookies.onChanged` that you refer to is only for browser extension https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/cookies/onChanged.

You can use the following npm package https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fcannizzaro/react-use-cookie-watcher.

If you check the implementation, it just adds a `setInterval` which reads cookies and waits for changes https://github.com/fcannizzaro/react-use-cookie-watcher/blob/9281ec0a5b6fbcbafd4589f0ea32d2b59bec32b3/src/index.tsx#L31.

So you can do it on your own if you want

Comment: have tried it before? it always return undefined